# Can we send parameters to trigger function which is not related to affected table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, parameters, triggers

Can we send parameters to trigger function which is not related to affected table in PostgreSQL? If I enter an active record of user there may some issue as if two different users active then trigger will confuse.

Comment: You can use the [`current_user[()]` (or just `user[()]`) & the `session_user[()]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) *functions* to access the role within PostgreSQL. -- If you use the same user/role for your entire application & you have "logical" users, you could store that information as well in the session via [custom session variables (which is really settings)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97095/set-session-custom-variable-to-store-user-id) or use a [temp table](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20130425020726.7f5ddf33%40james.intern).

Comment: You cannot supply variable parameters to a trigger function. Please describe your [real problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) instead. What do you want to achieve?